# "can't find bundle for base name" on JSF messages.properties

Tags: maven, jsf, resourcebundle

I am doing a simple JSF based project (please refer to [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWp5d.png) to check out the project structure) but I can't figure out why the faces-config can not reach to the Messages.

Here is the piece of code on the "faces-config.xml" that references the "Messages.properties" file:

```
    <application>
      <message-bundle>br.com.teste.primeiraaplicacaojsf.web.i18n.Messages</message-bundle>
      <locale-config>
        <default-locale>pt_BR</default-locale>
      </locale-config>
    </application>
```

Here is the error message generated on the browser:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Can't find bundle for base name br.com.teste.primeiraaplicacaojsf.web.i18n.Messages, locale pt_BR

type Exception report

message Can't find bundle for base name br.com.teste.primeiraaplicacaojsf.web.i18n.Messages, locale pt_BR

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Can't find bundle for base name br.com.teste.primeiraaplicacaojsf.web.i18n.Messages, locale pt_BR
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:671)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
root cause

java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name br.com.teste.primeiraaplicacaojsf.web.i18n.Messages, locale pt_BR
    java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1564)
    java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1387)
    java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1082)
    javax.faces.component.MessageFactory.getMessage(MessageFactory.java:161)
    javax.faces.component.MessageFactory.getMessage(MessageFactory.java:251)
    javax.faces.component.UIInput.validateValue(UIInput.java:1149)
    javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:982)
    javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1248)
    javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:712)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:253)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1195)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
```

Comment: Rename your Messages.properties to Messages_pt_BR.properties, build, deploy and see if it will work, please.

Comment: @Bonifacio the error persists. Exactly the same.

Comment: @Kukeltje It is in the right location within the structure, but I don't know how to check if it remains in that location after the deploy.

Comment: @Kukeltje I double checked it, the file is in the mentioned path inside structure, as shown in the image that I've linked.

Comment: Let your build system produce a WAR file. That represents the deployment. Now inspect that WAR file with a ZIP tool. Is the bundle file at the right location in there? (in its package structure in `/WEB-INF/classes`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason IntelliJ project explorer was showing the the path of the "Messages.properties" file as if it was a sequence of folders while behind the curtains it was creating just one folder with the whole path as it's name.
**The problem was fixed by remaking the folder structure inside the resources folder** (the files remain exactly the same).

Comment: yes indeed, IntelliJ created structure was not a set of folders but just one folder named org.abc.def.messages and all properties files were inside it. This was causing the issue. Need to create proper folders under src/main/resources i.e. /org/abc/def/messages and place .properties files there.